# Error while parsing YAML block of text

Tags: ruby, yaml

I am new to YAML, and have tried to do a YAML block but I am getting the following error:

> while scanning a block mapping: expected , but found: #< ScalarToken Value="content:   | This is a test of a test test test test A very very good test yeah yeah A test of test test" Style="None"> (line 8, column 1)

While it works fine without the |, I want whitespace preservation.

YAML file (Home.yml):

```
---
section:
    title: About this site
    content:    |
        This is a test of a test test test test
        A very very good test 
        A test of test test 
section:
    title: Source code
    content: |
        Licens:: BSD
        Link:: Here
        Foo 
...
```

Ruby code:

```
home = YAML.load_file('data/Home.yml')
home.inspect
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which YAML parser are you using?  Both the Ruby 1.8.7 parser and the parser in 1.9 parse the YAML in your question.

There's still trouble, through.  The syntax you've given is for a hash like this:

```
{
  'section' => {
    'title' => "About this site",
    'content => ...
  }
  'section' => {
    'title' => 'Source code',
    'content' => ...
  }
}
```

However, you can't have two hash keys be the same.  What happens is that the last one wins.  You may be looking for an array of hashes.  To do that, use this YAML syntax:

```
---
-
  section:
    title: About this site
    content: |
        This is a test of a test test test test
        A very very good test
        A test of test test
-
  section:
    title: Source code
    content: |
        Licens:: BSD
        Link:: Here
        Foo
```

Comment: I found out that YAML forbids tabs, and because it is a type of whitespace it was impossible for me to know by just looking at examples. I did correct the second thing to a list, as it was just something I forgot, but anyhow thank you for your help!

Comment: I am using the default? one of IronRuby 1.1.2 which should be Ruby 1.9 compatible

Comment: @Yet Another Geek: Oh, yes, tabs: the gift that keeps on giving.  I'm glad you got it straightened out.